# How can I: Make one div "follow" another, clean-up motion, and keep things within a window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've currently got a bunch of animals (".animalorb" divs) roaming around the screen, but I have a few problems:

1)  I need all the divs (".animalorbs") to stay on the screen.
2)  I want the random motion to be more elegant and less jerky.
3)  The amount of processing required with my current solution makes the page hard to run.

Here's a codepen for what I've got:

http://codepen.io/Bassitenor/pen/KWeLLE   (A snippet of the animating code is below)

```
function makeNewPosition(){

// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = $(window).height() - 50;
var w = $(window).width() - 50;

var nh = Math.floor(Math.random([3,4,5], [6,7,8]) * (h/2));
var nw = Math.floor(Math.random([3,4,5], [6,7,8]) * (w/2));

return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(c){
    var moveit = makeNewPosition();
    $(c).animate({ top: moveit[0], left: moveit[1] },  10000, "linear",     function(){
      animateDiv(c);        
    });
```

Here's a codepen with more elegant randomness and less "crashy" behavior by the page:

http://codepen.io/Bassitenor/pen/aJLmKV

The SECOND pen (the one with the manta rays) isn't using all the individual divs, though--it's just generating a single div over and over.

Can anyone help me either generate better code for the first page or help me merge the code on the first and second pages?

Thanks so much!
- Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could greatly improve performance by scaling the images down in an image processing software. At the moment they are all Full HD, which is a lot of work to scale down and animate in real time for every image.

As the width and height of the animal orbs are 100px, an image size of 100x100px would be sufficient.

Here is a jsFiddle of your code from codepen 1 but with the image exchanged by placeholder images of a smaller size (with `background: url("http://placehold.it/100x100");`): 
https://jsfiddle.net/t18rhz61/